# getBytes() works as expected under Windows (Java9) and does nor works under Linux

Tags: java, linux, encoding, base64

Method getBytes() works as expected under Windows (Java9) and does nor works under Linux. Characterset() => UTF-8 on both systems. JVM Version => Java 9 (I tested open jvm and oracle jvm under Linux)
Code:

```
public static String createSign(String uri, String apiSecret) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    byte[] signBytes = calculateSignBytes(uri, apiSecret);
    return bytesToHexString(signBytes);
}

private static byte[] calculateSignBytes(String uri, String secret) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    try {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
        mac.init(secretKeySpec);
        return mac.doFinal(uri.getBytes());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static String bytesToHexString(byte[] bytes){
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

the same under Windows and Linux. I also tested compiling and export executable JAR under windows and rut it on Linux, all functionality works fine except code above.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying a `Charset`? i.e. `secret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: Can you please describe, what is not working? in best Case you can give us an [MCVE] and the expected output and the output you get

Comment: Code that should invoke methods above:

str = prepareEncodingString( "/aaa/bbb$parameter=ZZZ", "765765", "htgfk5i7kjhvkyutr7i6"); httpsURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "DDDDD " + str); httpsURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); ... public String prepareEncodingString( String urlString, String clientId, String clientSecret ) { ... try { s = createSign(s, clientSecret.trim()); } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } String r = resultTemplate.replace("$VVVV",clientId.trim() ); ... return r; }

Answer (score 0):

Please remember always use the charset, this avoid unexpected results.

```
new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes ( Charsets.UTF_8 ), ALGORITHM)
```

Comment: Tested now : new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes ( Charsets.forName("UTF-8") ), ALGORITHM);
does not work.